# Ошибка работы программы на C

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h> // подключение библиотеки элементарных математических функций
#include <stdio.h> // подключение библиотеки функций ввода-вывода данных
#include <windows.h> // подключение библиотеки функций, связанных с операционной системой Windows
int main() {
   SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
   float a;
   float b;
   float c;
   printf("Введите значение переменной a=");
   scanf("%f",a);
   printf("Введите значение переменной b=");
   scanf("%f",b);
   return;
}
```

После ввода значения a программа завершается с данным сообщением:
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.401 s
Press any key to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%f",&a);
...
scanf("%f",&b);
```

потому что вы должны указать, **куда** следует читать значения.

Comment: Да и к `return` возвращаемое значение стоит добавить

Comment: @avp Да, кстати. И как оно вообще скомпилировалось? :)

Comment: Мой `gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`  тоже этого не понимает